# How do I move to a created Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I created an activity and I want to attach a fragment to this activity.
there is my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
FragmentManager fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}



@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.nav_home){
    }


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
    }


}
```

1.From here I want that the item "nav_home" on "onNavigationItemSelected" method will take me to a fragment I'll create.

2.I also want this fragment to be on my main activity.

How do I do both of these requirements?
Please help me from the part of making the fragment itslef.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok
first add this function

```
  public void displayView(int viewId) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);

        switch (viewId) {
            case R.id.nav_go:
                fragment = new GoFragment();
                title = "Go Now";
                viewIsAtHome = true;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_trips:
                fragment = new TripsFragment();
                title = "MY Trips";
                viewIsAtHome = false;
                break;



        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
        // set the toolbar title
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
```

and

edit this

```
  @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        displayView(id);
        return true;
    }
```

and simply in onCreate  add this

```
    displayView(R.id.nav_home);
```

.......................................

to create new fragmet

```
  @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public static class OnlineFragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_online, container, false);
           Button b1 = (Button) rootview.findbyid(R.id.s)
            return rootview;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah but the onNavigationItemSelected is a drawer with few options, every option need to take me to different fragment

Comment: more Explain please

Comment: Currently nav_home is just an item on Menu.xml
I want that Item to direct me to a fragment.
this same fragment I want it to be the "Home screen" of the app.
another thing is that the "onNavigationItemSelected" method is the method that take a click of one of the items on the menu and redirect the user to another fragment/activity.
what you made is that the method will just take me to this exact fragment while i have more items on the list

Comment: Ok  just use the Code 
and If you Clicked in Home , the fragment class you select will shown
do you ask how to create fragment to home?

Comment: Yes , how do I do that?

Comment: Do I write the fragment in a new class?

Comment: you can create it as Inner class .. Like I did
or in new class

Comment: Thank you so much!!!
Last thing- viewIsAtHome = true;
gives me an error, what should I do?

Comment: Just remove it 
viewIsAtHome  is if you pressback BTN